# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 65 path $.data

Tags: json, web-services, gson

I am trying to use Gson library to parse an api response. Here is the response String:

```
{
"data": {
  "Thresh": {
     "id": 412,
     "title": "Zincirli Gardiyan",
     "name": "Thresh",
     "key": "Thresh"
  },
  "Aatrox": {
     "id": 266,
     "title": "Darkin Kılıcı",
     "name": "Aatrox",
     "key": "Aatrox"
  },
  "Tryndamere": {
     "id": 23,
     "title": "Barbar Kral",
     "name": "Tryndamere",
     "key": "Tryndamere"
  },
  "Gragas": {
     "id": 79,
     "title": "Kavgacı Ayyaş",
     "name": "Gragas",
     "key": "Gragas"
  },
  "Cassiopeia": {
     "id": 69,
     "title": "Yılanın Şefkati",
     "name": "Cassiopeia",
     "key": "Cassiopeia"
  },
  "type": "champion",
  "version": "4.14.2"
  }
}
```

Here are my classes:

```
public class Champion {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String name;
    private String key;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

and response class:

```
public class ChampionsResponse {

    private String type;
    private String version;
    private Map<String, Map<String, Champion>> data;
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    public Map<String, Map<String, Champion>> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Map<String, Map<String, Champion>> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I use the following line to use gson library:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
try{
    ChampionsResponse championsResponse = gson.fromJson(response, ChampionsResponse.class);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But i get the exception saying that "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 65 path $.data..". Can anyone tell me where i am mistaken?

Thanks

Comment: @admdrew sorry, that is my mistake. Response string was lon so i tried to cut it but i forgot to put the last curly brace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, i need to use

```
private Map<String, Map<String, String>> data;
```

instead of

```
private Map<String, Map<String, Champion>> data;
```